# In pyQT5 how do you conditionally hide a tab in a widget?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I've created a widget and I've applied several form layouts to tabs within the widget. I would like to make some tabs available based on some boolean flags.

I've tried `tab_my_tab.setEnabled(False)` which disables the content of the tab, but it doesn't hide the tab. I'd like it if the tab is completely hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution to my question. I was able to hide one or more tabs by using the `setTabVisible(index, bool)` method on the `QTabWidget()`.

To hide multiple tabs you have to start hiding the highest index number tab first before hiding the lower index number tabs.

Comment: Or always hide the lowest index of tabs for as many tabs that have to be hidden: `for i in range(countOfTabsToHide):` `tabWidget.setTabVisible(indexOfFirstTabToHide, False)`